# Flutter loading Image asset too slow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I have a screen which shows a text and an image above the text and loads, in background, some data from the shared preferences.

But the image is taking forever to load, and when I remove the call to get the shared preferences data the image loads very quiclky. Do someone knows if I'm doing something wrong with this call?

here's the code:

```dart
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(AssetImage(Images.tomato), context);
    _loadData(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
              Strings.appName,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.black,
                fontSize: 50.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            Image.asset(Images.tomato),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _loadData(BuildContext context) async {
    final PreferencesRepository repository = PreferenceRepositoryImp();
    repository.loadAll().then(
      (_) {
        sleep(Duration(seconds: 2));
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Routes.HOME, (_) => false);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and that's the image

[image: "tomato"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `sleep(Duration(seconds: 2));` which halts *everything*. You should not be using `sleep`, especially inside a `build` method. Dart is *single* threaded so that means when it halts a thread, it prevents the UI from being built.

Also, why is `_loadData` marked as `async` if you're not using the `await` keyword? You only need it if you're going to use the `await` keyword, otherwise, remove it. If you want to make use of it, you should use `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2))` which makes it wait. Here:

```
void _loadData(BuildContext context) async {
  final PreferencesRepository repository = PreferenceRepositoryImp();
  await repository.loadAll();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Routes.HOME, (_) => false);
}
```

## How does `await` differ from `sleep`?

`await` makes Dart say "Hey, I'm going to keep my eye out for this in the future" (haha get it? Future? hahahhahaha I'm funny). Anyways, it won't continue the `_loadData` function because it wants that value but it will keep running (in your example) the build method and then when the `Future` comes back with a value, it will be like "Hey! There's that value I was looking for! Now I can keep running that function!"

`sleep` on the other hand makes Dart say "I'm going to take a nap for the duration of time I get" (in this case two seconds). It won't do anything until it "wakes up" since Dart is single-threaded. After it takes its two-second nap, it will continue the function and after it finishes, the build method will carry on, therefore, loading your image which explains why it takes so long.